# Analog-to-digital conversion time on MSP430FR6989

Tags: microcontroller, adc, time

Where can I get or calculate the time it takes for the analog-to-digital conversion? I'm using a MSP430FR6968. I've looked in the datasheets but couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Page 62 of [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr6989.pdf?ts=1668090811406&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) datasheet

Answer (score 5):

Rather than just give an answer detailing exactly which page this is on, or giving the straight answer, this will be more of an answer explaining how to navigate through the datasheet to get to the section you want so in future, you can find the information yourself easily. If you open the PDF of a TI Microcontroller, take note of the sections. You are looking for the ADC timing specifications. Close to the top of the [DATASHEET](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430fr6989.pdf?ts=1668090811406&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F) you will find a table of contents.

As you can see in this particular datasheet, there is a Specifications section (5) and a sub-section for timing and switching characteristics (5.13) as seen here:

[image]

It does take a while to scroll through all of this, but in most PDF viewers, you will have some contents options down the left hand side. You can expand section 5.13  to narrow down what you are looking for. You can see there is another subsection for peripherals (5.13.5) and this can yet again be expanded and one of the section details the ADC (5.13.5.5):

[image]

From here, scroll to the relevant section, which will be the timing parameters. On this particular datasheet, it can be found on page 62, in table 5-25 "12-Bit ADC, Timing Parameters":

[image]

All the information you need will be in this table.

Comment: Note that this only gives a minimum, except for specific configuration examples.  The actual conversion time depends on the clock configuration of the entire system, the bus the ADC peripheral is on, and the ADC filter if any, and those relationships are generally defined in a reference manual covering an entire family of chips, not in the datasheet (although some vendors, including Texas Instruments, do combine those two documents together)

Comment: @BenVoigt this does give a min and max for the internal oscillator, which assumes using this for the ADC. I should have included note 2 in the screenshot maybe, but there is usually enough information there to work it out based on the clock you're using for the ADC